# How to fix my onClick cardView that is returning other figures

Tags: android, mobile, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a recycler that is showing a list of items, there price and status. When I click on a card, I want it to show the price of the item that I have clicked on. However whenever, I click. The card returns the data of other cards and no the particular card that I have clicked.

```
    public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {
private TextView viewName, viewPrice;
private CheckBox viewAvailability;

private Context context;
private List<Item> listItems;

@NonNull
@Override
public ItemAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ItemAdapter.ItemHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = listItems.get(position);
    holder.setDetails(item);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}


public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ItemHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        viewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewName);
        viewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewPrice);
        viewAvailability = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewAvailability);


        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


            }
        });
    }

    public void setDetails(Item item) {
        viewName.setText(item.getName());
        viewPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
        int as = item.getAvailabilityStatus();

        if (as == 1) {
            viewAvailability.setChecked(true);
        } else {
        }
    }
}

public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> objects) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listItems = objects;
}
```

}

Comment: where is code you have used for onClick ?

Comment: inside Onclick , you did nothing.

Comment: Your onClick method in empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,put itemView onclick listner inside setDetails

```
public void setDetails(Item item) {
        viewName.setText(item.getName());
        viewPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
        int as = item.getAvailabilityStatus();

        if (as == 1) {
            viewAvailability.setChecked(true);
        } else {
        }

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // here you will able to access valid item
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain reason sir

Comment: Questioner, have used the right approach there to perform the click inside the `ItemHolder `...What is the reason behind to perfom the clik inside the `onBindViewHolder ` method

Comment: in setDetails  methods  a valid item  object is passed  so if  item.getName() and item.getPrice() are valid then on click surely he will access  proper item object

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `itemView.setOnClickListener` use set clickListener on your cardView and use `getAdapterPosition()` to track which item you click

```
 cardView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            int price = getThePrice(getAdapterPosition());
            // use price here
            }
        });
```

you have to create `getThePrice()` method here which will return you the price of item you click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {


private Context context;
private List<Item> listItems;

@NonNull
@Override
public ItemAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ItemHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = listItems.get(position);
    holder.viewName.setText(item.getName());
    holder.viewPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
    int as = item.getAvailabilityStatus();

    if (as == 1) {
        holder.viewAvailability.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.viewAvailability.setChecked(false);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}


public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView viewName, viewPrice;
    private CheckBox viewAvailability;

    public ItemHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        viewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewName);
        viewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewPrice);
        viewAvailability = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewAvailability);




        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


            }
        });
    }
}

public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> objects) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listItems = objects;
}
```

}